# What must I do to let an aspx.vb file see a .vb file in the same project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting a compile error "*Type 'commonClass' is not defined*" in a file directly beneath the project (\\alf.aspx > alf.aspx.vb) on this line of code:

```
Dim pDAO As New commonClass
```

There is such a class, in \\App_Code\commonClass.vb:

```
Public Class commonClass
```

What is needed for "alf" to see "commonClass"?

This is probably a very basic (no pun intended) question, but I am a newbie to VB.

### UPDATE

Does this have anything to do with the code in the legacy project "seeing" the other code, and the new one not: in the legacy project, the Visual Studio menu items are:

```
FILE
EDIT
VIEW
**WEBSITE**
BUILD
DEBUG
. . .
```

...whereas in the new project, they are:

```
FILE
EDIT
VIEW
**PROJECT**
BUILD
DEBUG
. . .
```

IOW, the new project (which I created using File > New Project > Templates > VB > New Project) has a "PROJECTS" menu item, whereas the legacy project has a "WEBSITE" menu item.

Will re-doing it as File > New Website > ... make the difference? Is there a way to change it to a website without going through that?

### UPDATE 2

Both the legacy code, which compiles, and the new project, which doesn't, contain:

```
// alf.aspx.vb
Partial Class alf
    Inherits Page
```

-and:

```
// App_Code\commonClass.vb
Public Class commonClass
```

I see no "Namespace" in either file...

### UPDATE 3

So, wondering if the fact that I created a new project rather than a new website is the crux of the problem, I tried creating a new website, but it tells me, "*An item with the same key has already been added*" and then the WebSite project - which I have not touched beyond creating it - starts off with 21 Errors and 13 Warnings

Comment: Are both classes in the same namespace?

Comment: Please see update 2

Comment: Is the file's build action set to Compile?

Comment: @Crowcoder: Interesting - in the legacy app, the File has a File Name and Full Path properties; in the new app, it has several properties, and the Build Action is set to "Content"

Comment: Set it to Compile

Comment: Should all files be set to that?

Comment: Code files, yes. Typically anything in App_Code folder.

Comment: Okay, they all are; the two in App_Code were the only two I had to change to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this wide-ranging and confounding issue with a three-pronged approach, which is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985897/what-is-wrong-with-this-type-of-aspx-code/41027959#41027959).

Answer (score 2):

You have two files.  One for your asp.net file (alf.aspx.vb) and one for your commonClass (I assume commonClass.vb).  Do both of these files have a `Namespace` defined and are they both the same Namespace (alf)?  If they don't match then you will get the error you are describing.

```
Namespace alf
    Public Class commonClass
        Public Shared Sub Execute()
            Console.WriteLine("Blah")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Neither file has a Namespace defined.