# How can I see all the References that are included in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reference, assemblies

I am trying to get a legacy project to compile, but failing so far ignominiously, as can be seen [rot cheer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985897/what-is-wrong-with-this-type-of-aspx-code) and [over yonder](https://forums.asp.net/t/2111565.aspx?Why%20do%20I%20get%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object%20Warnings%20and%20a%20blind%20Error%20).

In an attempt to track down just what the problem is, I want to see which References the project is using. There is no "References" folder in the Solution Explorer (and no "Show All Files" button).

When I select Website > Add Reference..., the Solution.Projects pane of the Reference Manager shows me "No items found." Shouldn't this be where the References used by the Solution are displayed?

If I select Assemblies.Framework or Assemblies.Extensions there, I do see a ginormous list of DLs, with some of them checked, but not those that I have tried to add to the project. I can see these when I expand the Browse.Recent section, and see there in the pane the DLLs that I have tried to add checked:

[image]

Does this mean that these references are included in the project, as I want them to be? Why isn't there a place that will show me *all* the references used by the project/website? Or is there, and I'm not seeing it?

### UPDATE

Here is what I see when I right-click the project:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: right-click the project, then select Start Options... > References:

[image]

Note the most intuitive place to stash it.

Comment: you beat me to it. Indeed not very intuitive at all

Answer (score 1):

if there are no References in the Solution Explorer tree then you can right click on the project name and then select Properties.

Now you should now see all the references. There should be a section called exactly that, References. I've seen that happen with older projects, done in VB.Net.

More details.

The Properties you see depend on what type of project it is as well. If this is applicable, try to avoid opening the project as a website, instead open it from its project or solution file.

Comment: There is no "Properties" option there, only a "Properties Window" which does not contain anything about references.

Comment: I think I have such  a project at work, I'll post a screenshot tomorrow.