# Why do source control entries keep getting added back to my .sln file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, asp.net-3.5, source-control-bindings, sln-file

I was able to finally get a legacy ASP.NET project to run which I have been tasked to maintain. A question about it and my tentative auto-answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985897/what-is-wrong-with-this-type-of-aspx-code).

In a nutshell, it seems one of the things I needed to do to get it to run was to clean out the TFS files and sections referring to them in the .sln file.

As to the latter, I remove these entries from the solution (.sln) file:

```
SccProjectName = "SAK"
SccAuxPath = "SAK"
SccLocalPath = "SAK"
SccProvider = "SAK"
```

...but they have been added back for some reason, so that my .sln contains them again, and for context/full disclosure is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.40629.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "MembersOrderEntry", "MembersOrderEntry", "{7D7D3972-0891-4600-BCBC-

CA40B0D0FF6E}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv3.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/MembersOrderEntry"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MembersOrderEntry\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MembersOrderEntry\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/MembersOrderEntry"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "MembersOrderEntry\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\MembersOrderEntry\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "2030"
        VWDDynamicPort = "false"
        SlnRelativePath = "MembersOrderEntry\"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual Basic"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {7D7D3972-0891-4600-BCBC-CA40B0D0FF6E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {7D7D3972-0891-4600-BCBC-CA40B0D0FF6E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {7D7D3972-0891-4600-BCBC-CA40B0D0FF6E}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Why are the "SAK" entries added back, and how can I prevent that from occurring again? This project is not under source control.

When I open the solution, I see a message that says, "...mappings could not be found ... temporarily disconnected..." Why is it even expecting to find mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder that the project exists in is mapped to TFS as a Workspace. You will need to move the files or remove the workspace or Visual Studio will keep adding Source Control back.

Comment: My CVS plugin (not TFS) is not active (git is selected for source control) and VS2019 keeps adding the old plugin settings' to the project. SO annoying. Changing the path where my project resides solved this, but I'm so frustrated after three hours of debugging, hacking, installing, uninstalling.... I'm afraid this will bite me back again in the future. It would be nice to know where VS caches this information.